# Insert into backstack wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, back-stack

I have an application with the following pages:

- Login
- Menu
- Chat

when I start the application the order of the pages is the following Login -> Menu -> Chat

But... when my application is not running and I get a push notification I want to navigate the user directly to the chat window(and do the login in the background, without the login page). My problem comes at this point, because when I press back I would like to go to the menu page, and when pressing back again I want to go to the login page.

I dont want to navigate the user through the login and menu page before going to chat if he clicks a push notification.

Any suggestions?

Comment: in what are your pages nested?

Comment: PhoneApplicationPage.. or what do you mean by that question?

Comment: you can navigate through the login and the menu page in the load?

Comment: I could, but it would look stupid that I jump trough 2 pages before getting where I want, and time consuming as well. unless there is a way to load those pages without the user noticing that.

Comment: do it before the `initializeComponent` then nothing is added and they dont see it or you can hang events on the Back button on each page

Comment: in order to do that I have to pass a parameter which determinate s weather I want to go to chat, or start normaly, and I can only read this in the OnNavigatedTo, (which is after InitializeComponent) or I am missing something?

Comment: can you not set a get parameter in the Toast?

Comment: I can, but as far as I know I can only read that parameter in the OnNavigatedTo, or not?

Comment: Also... NavigationService is null in the constructor of the page, so I can't do that :(

Comment: im at work now and got only PHP atm so I will try to look at it tonight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution I can think of would be that you remenmber you came to the Chat page from a push notification. Then when Back key is pressed on the Chat page you you catch the event (OnBackKeyPress) and call NavigationContext.NavigateTo(MainPage) by yourself. You can do the same same on the Menu page.

Comment: That is what I'm thinking of as well, I am searching for a more elegant solution...